# Render django view via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Suppose I have

```
def bar(request):
    template = loader.get_template('activation/bar_chart.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,{'name':'bar_chart'})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I want to send a http get request via the javascript in the template

```
$.get('/bar/')
```

But it does not render the bar_chart.html, I still stay in the current html page.

If I use the load function in the jquery

```
$('body').load('/bar/')
```

then the content of bar_chart.html will replace the body of the current html page. But I want to go to a new page (that is, the url should be /bar)

How can I do that with django and jquery?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the `/bar/` page you just need to change the `location` property.  JQuery is not needed here:

```
location.href = "/bar/";
```

Comment: That won't actually render the view via JS though...it'll just handle the redirect via JS. It sounds like the OP wants to `load` the `/bar/` data into the current template, and then update the URL via the history api.

Comment: @rnevius but why would they want to do that?

Comment: I want to direct to the new page of the URL, not just load the page. Where can I set location.href?

Answer (score 0):

I think i've run into this issue before as well.
If I remember correctly you can do the following

`return HttpResponse(template.render(context), mimetype='application/json')`

Comment: So I can use $.get('/bar/'), then the current page will direct to the /bar/?

Comment: I'm sorry i missed that part. I think what you want is basically use pjax this library [https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). . A lot better than managing html5 states.